# How to run a subprocess inside Google Cloud Function?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, subprocess, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to run a subprocess inside my cloud function to trigger my dataflow pipeline which is written in an external file.

```
import base64
import subprocess

def hello_pubsub(event, context):

    if 'data' in event:
        name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')

    else:
        name = 'World'
    print('Hello {}!'.format(name))
    var = subprocess.run(["python", "./defaultTrigger.py", "--input_topic", " projects/my_project/subscriptions/sub1" ,"--output_topic", "projects/my_project/topics/topic2"])
```

Ps : my dataflow pipeline reads from sub1 and writes into topic2.

My cloud function is triggered by pubsub.

> CompletedProcess(args=['python', '...', ... ] ,
>   returncode=1

Comment: Cloud Functions is a managed runtime that doesn't have a way for you to do this. You might want to look at Cloud Run, which is in many ways similar to Cloud Functions, but which runs a container you build. You likely *can* do the kind of thing your asking in Cloud Run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replied you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588368/how-to-trigger-a-dataflow-with-a-cloud-function-python-sdk/58592043?noredirect=1#comment103497443_58592043)

> The other part is your wish to perform a subprocess in Function and to call "python" in this subprocess. Remember, you are in serverless architecture, you don't know what is the underlying server, OS and platform. Performing a subprocess python can lead to unexpected thing (python 2 or 3? Which dependencies?...) if the call is accepted. Indeed, you are billed for the request processing time. If you fork the process and run background thread, the billing is not fair. That's why it's forbidden to perform this kind of operation. I recommend you to redesign your app