# Dataflow Job to start based on PubSub Notification - Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am writing a Dataflow job which reads from BigQuery and does a few transformations.

```
data = (
    pipeline
    | beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query='''
    SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime` LIMIT 100
    ''', use_standard_sql=True)
    | beam.Map(print)
)
```

But my requirement is to read from BigQuery only after receiving a notification from a PubSub Topic. The above DataFlow job should start reading data from BigQuery only if the below message is received. If it is a different job id or a different status, then no action should be done.

```
PubSub Message : {'job_id':101, 'status': 'Success'}
```

Any help on this part?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Beam's Wait transform (example here: https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/post/apache-beam-initialization-destruction-task) (I am not the author of the post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Cloud Functions, added the filtering logic in it and starting the Dataflow from there. Found the below link useful.
[How to trigger a dataflow with a cloud function? (Python SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588368/how-to-trigger-a-dataflow-with-a-cloud-function-python-sdk)

Answer (score 5):

That is fairly easy, the code would look like this

```
pubsub_msg = (
   pipeline
   | beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(topic=my_topic, subscription=my_subscription)
)

bigquery_data = (
    pubsub_msg
    | beam.Filter(lambda msg: msg['job_id']==101)   # you might want to use a more sophisticated filter condition
    | beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query='''
    SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime` LIMIT 100
    ''', use_standard_sql=True)
)
bigquery_data | beam.Map(print)
```

However, if you do it like that you will have a streaming DataFlow job running (indefinitely, or until you cancel the job), since using `ReadFromPubSub` results automatically in a streaming job. Consequently, **this does not start** a Dataflow job, when a message is arriving in PubSub, but rather one job is already running and listening to the topic for something to do.

If you actually want to trigger a Dataflow batch job, I would recommend using a [Dataflow template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/dataflow-templates#python), and starting this template with a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) which listens to your PubSub topic. The logic of the filtering would then be within this CloudFunction (as a simple `if` condition).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I check if the status is 'Success' for the job_id and only then proceed to the next step? The code looks like it will move to the ReadFromBigQuery task even if the Filter doesn't give any results.

Comment: `beam.Filter` expects a custom function that returns either true or false. Only those elements which return true are propagated down the line. So if your input returns always false, the `ReadFromBigQuery` is never executed. You may use any complex custom function you like (including checking on status in your case), see the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/filter/#example-1-filtering-with-a-function).