# Cloud Function to trigger a Dataflow job in Go

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow job written using the Python SDK. But I want to trigger this Dataflow Job using Cloud Functions which should written in Go. I found a thread similar to this which has the function written in Python [Trigger Dataflow with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588368/how-to-trigger-a-dataflow-with-a-cloud-function-python-sdk)

My flow would be like below:

1. PubSub Notification to trigger Cloud Functions
2. Cloud Functions written in Go to start a DataFlow Job written in Python

I can make the Dataflow SDK as a template. Any pointers on how I can trigger the Python Dataflow templates from Go? Or is there a better way for it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

check "google.golang.org/api/dataflow/v1b3" package

I don't have a way to test it, but I think it looks like a code like this

```
ctx := context.Background()
dataflowService, _ := dataflow.NewService(ctx)
jobService := dataflow.NewProjectsJobsService(dataflowService)
jobService.Get("project ", "job id").Do()
```

Comment: This looks good.

More specifically for templates though: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/dataflow/v1b3#ProjectsLocationsTemplatesLaunchCall

API Reference: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.templates/launch

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please let me know how to pass the template to this?

Comment: `
dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3')
request = dataflow.projects().templates().launch(
    projectId=project,
    gcsPath=template,
    body={
        'jobName': job,
        'parameters': parameters,
    }
)

response = request.execute()
`
I could find for Python. Is there something similar using Go?